# "Type error: Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\FrontController::detail(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected"

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I want to passing a data from Shirts to details, to know a detail of product from Shirts. How to do that? I have some error here 
[Error's Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVMiG.png)

This my web view
[web View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkcJF.png)

FrontController.php

```
 class FrontController extends Controller
{
  public function index()
  {
    $shirts=Product::all();
    return view('front.home', compact('shirts'));
  }
  public function shirts()
  {
    $shirts=Product::all();
    return view('front.shirts', compact('shirts'));
  }
  public function detail($id)
  {
      return view('front.shirt', ['detail' => Product::findOrFail($id)]);

  }
```

Route
Web.php

```
Route::get('/', 'FrontController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/shirts', 'FrontController@shirts')->name('shirts');
Route::get('/detail', 'FrontController@detail')->name('detail');
```

Shirts.blade.php

```
<a href="{{route('detail', $shirt->id)}}">
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161966/discussion-on-question-by-yudha-patria-type-error-too-few-arguments-to-functio).

Answer (score 2):

you missing argument in route('detail')
Edit to:

```
Route::get('/detail/{id}', 'FrontController@detail')->name('detail');
```

And Try again.Hope this help :D

Answer (score 0):

there is two three thing that need to change first is route file 
it should be like this

```
Route::get('/detail/{$id}', 'FrontController@detail')->name('detail');
```

from this you get that parameter $id that you passes in controller .

and for view as per i see  in your code there your route is

```
<a href="{{route('detail', $detail->id)}}">
```

which has to be like this

```
<a href="{{route('detail', $shirt->id)}}">
```

i think it might solve your problem 
hope it will help you

Answer (score -1):

I think in your Route you need to give Id parameter also,

```
Route::get('/detail/{id}', 'FrontController@detail')->name('detail');
```

Comment: when I give that, I have error like this....

"Missing required parameters for [Route: detail] [URI: detail/{$id}]. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\ecom\resources\views\front\home.blade.php)"

Comment: In view can you try like this,

<a href="{{ URL::to('detail' . $shirt->id . '' ) }}" >

Comment: same error.. "Missing required parameters for [Route: detail] [URI: detail/{$id}]. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\ecom\resources\views\front\home.blade.php)"